# performBatchUpdates after viewDidDisppear causing error?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios9

i am calling

```
performBatchUpdates({
            self.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPathes)
            },
            completion: {
                _ in
        })
```

on a collection view which in controller that is not visible ! there are already another view controllers which pushed above it.

this cause the following error:

```
Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (12), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (12 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

but that's not true at all because if  i am calling performBatchUpdates while the view is visible it will works perfect.

what's happened exactly ?

EDIT:
PLEASE note that if i call reloadData it works fine while the view is not visible. what does apples say about that ?

How can i catch this exception. so i could user reloadData instead ?

EDIT:
i have printed the following before calling performBachUpdates:

```
print("visibleCells().count :"  + String(self.visibleCells().count))
print("dataModel count:" + String(self.dataArray.count))
```

here is what i got:

```
visibleCells().count :0
dataModel count:12
```

it means that the exception is not true !!

Comment: You need to update the data model to match the items you insert into the collection view.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for your cmment. I've updated the data model before calling insetItemIndexPath.

Comment: @rmaddy this working great but the view controller should be visible !!

Comment: You should update it only when the view is visible. That is when you pop back to the view controller you are doing this batch update . Try doing it in the view will appear.

Comment: @AbinGeorge thank you for your reply, i use reloadData function. it works why ? does apple mention that in documentation

Comment: You need to explain what triggers this batch update because it looks like the table view has already processed the cap hangs and then you're telling it again...

Answer (score 1):

As @rmaddy mentioned in the comments, your issue is that you're not properly updating the data model.
You call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` for `indexPathes` (which contains 12 indexes), but your data model starts with 12 indexes and ends with 12 indexes after the batch update. You only need to call insert when you're inserting something in your data model (e.g. after calling something similar to `dataModel.insert("whatever", atIndex: 0)`, you may also call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` with index 0).
It doesn't seem to be the case here, since you end up with the same number of elements (12). In this case you need to call `reloadData` if you want to refresh the collection view (or don't call anything if data doesn't change)

`reloadData` doesn't throw such exceptions, since it doesn't add/remove anything, it will simply get whatever you provide in the data source. `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` can animate the changes, so it'll do some checks to see if your data model (whatever you provide in the data source) added the new elements, throwing an exception otherwise.
Catching the exception (using @try/catch) won't get you far, since it'll leave the updates in some weird state, causing further issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but that's not true. I've edited the question . you can see that the dataModel is filled properly

Comment: `visibleCells` has nothing to do with your data model. `visibleCells` will always be <= than your data model, it may be 0 or 3 or 12 (as long as 12 elements fit on the screen) or anything in between. All that matters is what `numberOfItemsInSection` shows prior to doing the updates and after (this is based on what you provide through `UICollectionViewDataSource` with `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)`.

Comment: alexi, i am pretty sure this a bug in ios. datamodel and indices paths are matched. any way Thank you for your efforts

Comment: @david - the exception does no check on the indices, it only cares of how many items are inserted and deleted (it checks the total count of cells before and after the batch update). If your collection view has 12 cells and you're telling it to insert another cell (at whatever index), it will expect to have 13 cells after the update.

Comment: yes i know, but that's not the case here . i have cleared the collection before inserting new item. I am done . i just replaced it with reloadData. Thanks